# Vexing object conversion error for null objects

Tags: java

I have some constructor code where I set many variables to `null` and wanted to shorten this to a single statement, but compilation fails.

Here's the simplest example I can think of:

```
class Bar{}
class Foo{}

class FooBar
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    FooBar()
    {
        foo = bar = null;
    }   
}
```

and the compiler outputs "Bar cannot be converted to a Foo". This I don't understand. There are no objects here. What is going on?

Comment: I'm sorry if this question is somehow written correctly. Perhaps you could explain to me what is wrong with it. Many thanks,

Comment: Setting variables to `null` in the constructor is unnecessary. They're already `null`.

Comment: Irrespective of what the compiler says "a = b = something" is bad style in Java.  Just don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't care that you're assigning a null (which would not be a problem). You're attempting to do an illegal assignment with `foo = bar` and the compiler refuses to go through with it.

You're thinking "I want these variables of type `Foo` and `Bar` to be null", but the compiler sees "He's trying to assign a `Bar` to a `Foo`".

Also the default value for non-local object variables *is* `null`, so are you sure that you're not trying to do something that's completely unnecessary anyway?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic thing. If you have 2 `int` type variable then you can do

```
a=b=10
```

What here happening is 10 is assigned to b and the value of b is assigned to a.

In your case you `foo` and `bar` are different type variables, null is assigned to `bar` but the value of `bar` can not be assigned to `foo` because its of another type. so it will generate error.